# div shift to left with page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this site [egtripper.com](http://egtripper.com/) and with page loading the slider section float to left instead of be in the center, see this [image](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/8401/kvw9.png) and when I try to inspect element with google chrome tool this problem disappear and the page be as expected see this [image](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/6035/7cqx.png)

this is the css code for the slider div

```
.slider {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 330px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
}
```

can any one help me solving this issue

Comment: To be honest the slider is being displayed centered on my browser (ff)

Comment: Looks fine. Whats the point in setting min-width and width as you have?

Comment: what screen size are you using? chrome dev tools, if attached to widow, is causing it to resize by reducing width, which may explain why it 'fixes' the problem.

Comment: It works fine at some people and this problem appears at some people

Comment: CodeToad >> I don't understand you

Answer (score 0):

Add to  `.wrapper` css style

```
.wrapper{
    text-align:center;
}
```

slider element has a set margin 0 auto so it is necessary to have more momentum to center the elements inside the wrapper